# Meaning of Syntax within method-template

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, function-templates

i have two questions about the following code:

```
  211 template<class Type>
  212 tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvsPatchField, surfaceMesh> >
  213 limitedSurfaceInterpolationScheme<Type>::flux //Return the interpolation  
                                                    //weighting factors.
  214 (                                             
  215     const GeometricField<Type, fvPatchField, volMesh>& phi
  216 ) const
  217 {
  218     return faceFlux_*this->interpolate(phi); //const surfaceScalarField& 
  219 }                                            //faceFlux_
```

1. Line 211 - 213: The shown method `flux(...)` should be a method-template where the return-type is `limitedSurfaceInterpolationScheme<Type>` . What does `tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvsPatchField, surfaceMesh> >` in this connection exactly mean?
2. Line 218: What does `faceFlux_*this` do? `faceFlux_` is member-object of class-template `limitedSurfaceInterpolationScheme<Type>` and `*this` is the content of the object method `flux(...)` was called on.

greetings
streight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvsPatchField, surfaceMesh> >` is return type of method `flux` from class `limitedSurfaceInterpolationScheme<Type>`. It's normal method from *class template*, not a *method template*.
2. `faceFlux_*this->interpolate(phi);` is exactly the same as `faceFlux_*(this->interpolate(phi));` - it's multiplication.

Comment: 1. Some detailed explanation? :)

Comment: method of class template defined outside of class body has this structure:

`template <list-of-class-template-type-parameters>`

`return-type class-name<list-of-class-template-type-parameters>::method-name(method-args)`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed clear writing would make it clear

```
  template<class Type>
  tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvsPatchField, surfaceMesh> >
  limitedSurfaceInterpolationScheme<Type>::flux(const GeometricField<Type,fvPatchField,volMesh> &phi ) const
   {
     return faceFlux_  *  this->interpolate(phi);  
   }
```

So from above it is clear that it is implementation of function which defined like this in header.

```
template<class Type>
class limitedSurfaceInterpolationScheme
{
  //before  c++ 11 we had to write nested template right angle bracket with space > >
//return_type fun_name(argument) 
tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvsPatchField, surfaceMesh> >  flux(const GeometricField<Type,fvPatchField,volMesh> &phi ) const ;// constant member function

}
```

For more see [How to define a template class in a .h file and implement it in a .cpp file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp)